# I have some Qs about ASCII code in C lang

Tags: c, ascii

In this code, Can I replace ASCII code with character such as 'a','z' etc..

```
int main()
{
    int ch = 0;
    ch = getchar();

    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        ch -= 32;
    else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        ch += 32;
    else
        ch = -1;

    if (ch == -1) {
        puts("nope");
        return 0;
    }

    putchar(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"Can I replace ASCII code with character such as `'a'`,`'z'`"*? Given that you're most probably *using* a computer where the basic execution character set is ASCII, then `'a'` is a constant of type `int`with value 97 - which is the ASCII code of *LATIN SMALL LETTER A*.

Comment: Do you mean replace `32` with `('a' - 'A')`?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i mean, Is it possible that put (ch >= 65) instead of (ch >= 'A') or operate such as ( char ch = 'A';  ch += 32;)

Comment: @박서형 You can, but there's no reason to as it make your code less portable and less readable.

Comment: There is not just one execution character set and enoding and it is almost certainly not ASCII. So, people are suggesting ways of avoiding unnecessary assumptions. There is a reasonable one, though, for the style of algorithm you are writing (if statements) and you could add it as a comment to your code: `// ASSUMPTION: In the execution character set, the range 'a' through 'z' is contiguous; the range 'A' through 'Z' is contiguous.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean *Is it possible to replace `if (ch >= 'A')` with `if (ch >= 65)`?*, yes it is possible, but **don't do it!**

Indeed you **should** use character constants instead of explicit ASCII values or other magical constants such as `32` in your code, because it makes the code both more readable and portable (although not completely portable as alphabetic characters do not form a contiguous set on EBCDIC systems for example, but with a constant offset between upper and lowercase). Furthermore, you should include `<stdio.h>` for correctness.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ch;
    ch = getchar();

    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')      // assuming lowercase letters form a contiguous set
        ch += 'A' - 'a';             // change to uppercase, assuming constant offset
    else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') // assuming uppercase letters form a contiguous set
        ch += 'a' - 'A';             // change to lowercase, assuming constant offset
    else
        ch = -1;

    if (ch == -1) {
        puts("nope");
        return 0;
    }

    putchar(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the C library has functions defined in `<ctype.h>` to handle case conversions that are portable to non-ASCII platforms and are quite readable too:

Here is a portable version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ch;
    ch = getchar();

    if (islower(ch))
        ch = toupper(ch);
    else if (isupper(ch))
        ch = tolower(ch);
    else
        ch = -1;

    if (ch == -1) {
        puts("nope");
        return 0;
    }

    putchar(ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seeing recent comments, I think the question was meant the other way around.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I'm afraid you right... Answer updated with stronger language.

Comment: @BoPersson: The character literals do not ensure portability but they do increase readability, in my opinion.

Comment: @BoPersson: *more portable* is short of *completely portable*, hence my second version described as *Here is a more portable version:*, which I shall rephrase a bit.